# What is meant by IPSec is "transparent"

Tags: ipsec

While reading a guide on IPSec, i came across this sentence:

> IPSec is transparent to the user and the applications.

Can someone please tell me what is meant by being transparent from security view point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. Transparent means it does not change anything for the user and application, so you don't have to rewrite your apps to use it, unlike TLS. You don't have to copy certificates and keys around etc. It is basically an ease of use thing. You just enable it and it works.

Comment: It also helps to know what layer it works at and how the layers work.  So, just like wifi, ethernet, serial, satellite, cell phone, modem, etc. are all "transparent" so is IPSec.  The stuff on the higher layers do not see the lower layers.

Answer (score 2):

It just means the user and the applications don't notice it. More of a UX perspective than a security one.